# Center a text inside a div with an image also

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm developing a web site and I to show something like this:

[image]

My current html code is this:

```
<body>
    <div id="about">
        <img src="images/aboutCardIcon.png"/>
        <span>About</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is this html code correct? Can I use span tag?

How can I center in the middle About text?

Comment: Is there only one of those? Or are there a few?

Comment: are the image's dimensions known?

Comment: yes, height is 126px on three cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements which are perfect for what you're trying (html5).

**[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dUjBp/)**

## The code used

### HTML

```
<figure>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Potato">
    <figcaption>A Potato</figcaption>
</figure>
```

### CSS

```
figure {
    border:     1px solid black;
    display:    inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding:    20px;
}

figure img {
    float:  left;
    height: 126px;
}

figcaption {
    float:       right;
    height:      126px;
    line-height: 126px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:   300%;
}
```

Most of the CSS is purely cosmetic, the important parts are the floats places on the image and the `<figcaption>`, and the set height and line-height on the `<figcaption>`.

P.S. the reason I made it white and not black like your example, is because the image I chose had a black background, and I didn't want it to look hideous. :)